# Form request is made three times: Status 200 OK

Tags: javascript, ajax

I created a form on `/contact-us` and having `action="/contact-us"`. Now, when I added Ajax to it, it is sending the request three times, i cannot find the reason.

Ajax:

```
define(['jquery', 'foundation.alert'], function($) {
  return {
    init: function() {
      $("#success-alert").hide();
      $("#error-alert").hide();
      $('button').click(function(e){
        $('input').map(function() {
          if(!$(this).val()) {
            $("#error-alert").show();
            $("#success-alert").hide();
            return false;
          } else {
            $('document').ready(function() {
              var form = $('#contact_us'); // contact form
              var submit = $('button');  // submit button
              var status = $('#form-status'); // alert div for show alert message

              // form submit event
              form.on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit

                $.ajax({
                  url: '/contact-us', // form action url
                  type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
                  dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
                  data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
                  beforeSend: function() {
                    submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
                  },
                  success: function(data) {
                    form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
                    $("#success-alert").show();
                    $("#error-alert").hide();
                    submit.html('Send'); // reset submit button text
                  },
                  error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                  }
                });
              });
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: If you submit it again, does it happen 6 times?

Comment: You're doing some very strange iteration... You have a click event, inside of which you're iterating over some elements using .map, and then on each iteration, binding a submit event on a form. You should likely bind to that submit event outside of the click event.

Comment: This is probably not your issue but are you `init`-ing this outside of your code using `$(document).ready(function(){ init; });`? If so then there is probably no need to listen for `.ready()` inside of the `init`

Comment: What could be the best solution to overcome this bug, like if i take the submit event outside the if else condition, e.PreventDefault will not work

Comment: The preventDefault would work...You are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through all the inputs and applying on submit for every input in your form. So if it is submitting 3 times, you must have three inputs. Each time you click the button, you will be adding even more submit handlers! The whole design of this is wrong.

You should not be attaching the submit handler inside of the click event, it should be outside and have it done one time. Do your validation inside of the submit handler to make sure that it is valid before making the Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution.

```
var wait = false;
```

wait variable for global scope

```
if (!wait) {
    wait = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/contact-us', // form action url
        type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
        dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
        data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
        beforeSend: function () {
            submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
        },
        success: function (data) {
            wait = false;
            form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
            $("#success-alert").show();
            $("#error-alert").hide();
            submit.html('Send'); // reset submit button text
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are just covering up the problem.

Comment: absolutly @epascarello :)

Comment: it actually ruined the functionality of Ajax - Page is now redirecting

Answer (score 0):

After going through my code i realized what mistakes i have been doing and also realized that reading code is more important than writing it.

This is how i rewrite the code and its working fine but i am still not sure if it is the best approach.

```
define(['jquery', 'foundation.alert'], function($) {
return {
init: function() {
    $("#success-alert").hide();
    $("#error-alert").hide();

  $(function () {
    $('#contact_us').on('submit', function (e) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/contact-us',
        data: $('#contact_us').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          $("#success-alert").show();
          $("#error-alert").hide();
        }

      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });

  $('button').click(function(e){
  $('input').map(function() {
           if(!$(this).val()) {
            $("#error-alert").show();
            $("#success-alert").hide();
            return false;
            }
        });
      });

    }
 }
});
```

Note: Never take writing code as a burden.